# Non-dimensionalization for spatially varying material parameters

Tags: dimensional-analysis

For a homogeneous material of length $L$, we can write the heat equation as $$\rho c\frac{dT}{dt}=k\frac{du^2}{dx^2}, \text{  } x\in (O,L)$$ where $T$ is the temperature, $\rho$ is the thermal conductivity, $c$ is specific heat, and $k$ is the thermal conductivity.

To non-dimensionalize it, I know that I can define a new variable for space $\hat{x}=\frac{x}{L}$, time $\hat{t}=\frac{kt}{L^2\rho c}$ and temperature $\hat{T}=\frac{T}{T_0}$ where $T_0$ is the initial temperature, using the chain rule, obtain the simplified form $$\frac{d\hat{T}}{dt}=\frac{du^2}{dx^2}.$$

When the material is heterogeneous, we often assume that the thermal conductivity varies in space and is modeled by the function $k=k(x)$.  When this is the case, I'm not quite sure what is the standard approach non-dimensionalization.

I conjecture that the process should still be similar even though $k(x)$ is not a constant.  Should I choose a reference thermal conductivity $k$ from the range of values $k(x), x\in (0,L)$ follow the same proceedure?  Is there an alternative methodology to non-dimensionalize in the case of spatially varying material parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about a convention, but I would normally write it as follows

$$k=k(x)=k(L \hat{x}) = k_0f(\hat{x}),$$

where $k_0$ is the pre-factor carrying the dimension and $f(\hat{x})$ the function determining the spatial variation, which can easily be derived from $k(x)$. This will give you

$$\frac{d\hat{T}}{d\hat{t}}=f(\hat{x})\frac{d\hat{u}^2}{d\hat{x}^2}.$$

In practical problems, the terms $x/L$ and $k_0$ naturally appear, e.g. $k(x)=k_0(1+b\frac{x}{L})$ would give you $f(x)=1+b\hat{x}$.